# What is ## used for?

Tags: python, comments

I have looked at other questions about this and the general consensus seems to be that `##` is used for commenting out code. However, in the Interactive Editor for Python, prefixing a line with `##` appears to make a sort of section header for the code. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python's syntax, a hash indicates the start of a comment, and all subsequent characters on the line are ignored. To quote [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#comments):

> A comment starts with a hash character (`#`) that is not part of a string literal, and ends at the end of the physical line. A comment signifies the end of the logical line unless the implicit line joining rules are invoked. Comments are ignored by the syntax; they are not tokens.

The second hash therefore has **no syntactic meaning** in Python itself.

However, assuming you mean [this specific "Interactive Editor for Python"](http://www.iep-project.org/), one of its features is:

> Matlab-style cell notation to mark code sections (by starting a line with `##`).

*Because* the comments are not meaningful syntax, tools are free to interpret and use them how they like. Another example of this is `pylint`, which allows specially-formatted comments (`# pylint: disable=message-name`) to [deactivate specific messages](http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message).